# Making a form Sticky

Tags: php, forms, variables, sticky

I'm trying to make a form sticky by setting the value of the name field set to a variable called "userName". When I try to set the value (see below) it doesn't work. It doesn't even pick up that the variable is there.

```
  function form1(){ 
        echo'<form method="POST" action="';echo$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

        echo'">

        <label> Name:</label><br><input type="text" name="userName"  value="';echo$userName;
        echo'"id="userName"/><br>
        <label> Password:</label><br><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br>
        <label> Submit:</label><br><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /><br>

    </form>';

};
```

Comment: Please clarify "it doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `$userName` anywhere inside of that function.
I assume you have defined it somewhere else?

In order to use it inside the function, you'll have to either make it global (seriously not recommended) or pass it to your function as a parameter.